# Unable to merge dex?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to run my project, but for some reason it gives me that error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>    com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

I saw few solutions, but none of them helps me. What I'm missing here?

**Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.world.bolandian.talent"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core: 2.2. 2 ', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.beardedhen:androidbootstrap:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.github.mukeshsolanki:country-picker-android:1.1.9'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: See [Configure your app for multidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-gradle). Also don't forget the multidex support dependencies and setup.

Comment: This has been a common error for me on Android Studio 3.0. You do not need to enable multidex unless you hit the 65k method limit which I doubt you are currently. WHat I do to solve this when it comes up is to a clean, enable multidex with `multiDexEnabled true`, build, remove multidex and build again

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question and post the entire Gradle Console output, not just this error message. The details of the cause of the error should be elsewhere in the Gradle Console output.

Comment: Its just give me that error. only these 2 lines

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Comment: Could be this? https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68144982

Answer (score 0):

add in Gradle

```
  defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

`dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'}`

in  Android Manifest

```
<application
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
 ...........
```

Comment: Tried this, but still got that error

Answer (score 0):

FirebaseUI has a strict dependency towards a fixed Firebase/Play Services Version that you have to comply to. Ergo, your versions are not in sync.

You use:

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.0'
```

and then

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'
```

However, **FirebaseUI 3.1.0** requires **Firebase/Play Services 11.4.2**.

The next version of FirebaseUI is **3.1.2**, which needs **Firebase/Play Services  11.6.2**.

For the full and future reference - the [FirebaseUI-Android dependencies list](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#dependencies).